# Rotate elements by scrolling

Tags: scroll, rotation

Would it be possible to rotate an element on a website by scrolling?

The element should rotate to the right while scrollong down the page, and to the left while scrolling up.

The pace of the rotation should match the pace of the scrolling.

When no longer scrolling the element should rotate back to the the starting point.

Comment: Not clear on what you mean by this.  If you just mean using whatever control is used for scrolling to rotate something instead, the answer should be yes.  HOW this might be accomplished would depend on what system you're using.

Comment: @ScottHunter - What do you mean by system? It is for a website - the user should still be able to scroll down the page, but while doing so, the element should rotate as described in my question. Do you now how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking into the same thing and here is the info I have come across in hopes that you may find what you are looking for.

1) This could be achieved using jquery's .scroll and some CSS3 transitions, however it is not widely supported yet. IE doesnt support it at all at the time of this writing so you would want to know your target audience. This could be done with some fixes and workarounds to get more support in different browsers but you are better off going with a different option, unless you really want that 'Do It Yourself' feel.

2) Like option 1 it would be using .scroll and calling to a rotation plugin (cause using the jquery's rotators are not so smooth). If thats the route you would like to take, check this plugin out  http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

3) The way I would go is using one of the many parallax scrolling plugins that have rotation built in. Most of them have a graceful degradation implemented for those IE folk. Two of my favorites would be:
http://johnpolacek.github.com/scrollorama/
and
http://joelb.me/scrollpath/

Hope this points you in the right direction!